# Remove selected user from User picker in Google App maker

Tags: google-app-maker

In the User Picker widget after I pick a user and then select the same user after clearing the value (

> `widget.value = null;`

), selecting that user does not trigger the onValueChange event (because it is not a regarded as a newValue).

Even in the [Training Hub example](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/training-hub/) this issue is present.

Issue it causes: If I add a user then delete it I cannot add the user again until I add a different user which changes the value of the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when you clear the value, I use this script when exiting a page/popup with a user picker on it. This way the user picker does not retain the last user selected when returning to that page/popup. This script is usually in the onClick of a button to cancel/submit/exit/etc., which is why you can't use widget.value. You will need to use your own page/widget names as appropriate -

app.popups.Popup1.children.Content.children.Form1.children.Form1Body.children.UserPicker1.value = null;